# Password checking in dojo

Tags: javascript, security, dojo

I want to check that two passwords are the same using Dojo.

Here is the HTML I have:

> `<form id="form" action="." dojoType="dijit.form.Form" /`>
>
> `<p`>Password: `<input type="password"
>
>       name="password1"
>
>       id="password1"
>
>       dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
>
>       required="true"
>
>       invalidMessage="Please type a password" /`>`</p`>
>
> `<p`>Confirm:  `<input type="password"
>
>       name="password2"
>
>       id="password2"
>
>       dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
>
>       required="true"
>
>       invalidMessage="This password doesn't match your first password" /`>`</p`>
>
> `<div dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="onSave"`>Save`</div`>
>
> `</form`>

Here is the JavaScript I have so far:

> `var onSave = function() {
>
>       if(dijit.byId('form').validate()) { alert('Good form'); }
>
>       else { alert('Bad form'); }
>
>   }`

Thanks for your help. I could do this in pure JavaScript, but I'm trying to find the Dojo way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you a lot closer

- setting intermediateChanges=false keeps the validator running at every keystroke.
- the validation dijit's constraint object is passed to its validator.  Use this to pass in the other password entry
- dijit.form.Form automatically calls isValid() on all its child dijits when it's submitted, and cancels submittion if they don't all validate.  I though the invalid ones would get their error message, but they don't. That's left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

the validation function:

```
function confirmPassword(value, constraints)
{
    var isValid = false;
    if(constraints && constraints.other)  {
        var otherInput =  dijit.byId(constraints.other);
        if(otherInput) {
            var otherValue = otherInput.value;
            console.log("%s == %s ?", value, otherValue);
            isValid = (value == otherValue);
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
function onsubmit()
{
    var p1 = dijit.byId('password1').value;
    var p2 = dijit.byId('password2').value;
    return p1 == p2;
}
```

and the input objects:

```
<p>Password: <input type="password"
    name="password1"
    id="password1"
    dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
    required="true"
    intermediateChanges=false
    invalidMessage="Please type a password" /></p>

<p>Confirm: <input type="password"
    name="password2"
    id="password2"
    dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
    required="true"
    constraints="{'other': 'password1'}"
    validator=confirmPassword
    intermediateChanges=false
    invalidMessage="This password doesn't match your first password" /></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even easier, use the pre-written Dojox widget, **dojox.form.PasswordValidator**.

http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/form/PasswordValidator

It does everything you want straight out of the box!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it!

This [page on the Dojo forum](http://dojotoolkit.org/forum/dijit-dijit-0-9/dijit-support/password-confirmation-validation) was helpful.

I changed the HTML for the confirm password to:

> `<p>Confirm: <input type="password"
>
>   name="password2"
>
>   id="password2"
>
>   dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
>
>   required="true"
>
>   validator="return theSame(this, dijit.byId('password1'));"
>
>   invalidMessage="This password doesn't match your first password" /></p>`

The only difference is the added *validator* parameter.

And I created the following JavaScript function:

> `function(dojoTxt1, dojoTxt2) {
>
>     return dojoTxt1.getValue() == dojoTxt2.getValue();
>
>   }`

I think you can also use the *validator* parameter to create regular expressions to test against, but the [documentation](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/dijit/1.2/dijit.form.ValidationTextBox.validator) isn't very clear.

Comment: I think that Ed's solution takes into account multiple constraints and is a more complete solution to the question.

Comment: You're right. I just hadn't got round to looking because I'd solved the problem enough for my needs when he answered it.